# npm dependency resolution git+ssh

Tags: git, npm

I have a problem with npm's dependency resolution after updating to npm v7.
Before the update on of my nested dependencies was resolved as followed using github as repository.

```
"requires": {
        "cls-hooked": "github:alexgarbarev/cls-hooked",
// ...
}, 
// ...

"cls-hooked": {
      "version": "github:alexgarbarev/cls-hooked#b65ea3b767d5756c71aa8b734c1faac851451dc1",
      "from": "github:alexgarbarev/cls-hooked",
      "requires": {
        "async-hook-jl": "^1.7.6",
        "emitter-listener": "^1.0.1"
      }
    },
```

Since the update and clean installation the resolved dependencies now use git+ssh:// as protocol.
On my local machine this is fine but in continuous integration environment there is no ssh-key available to fetch these repositories from github using ssh.

```
"resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/alexgarbarev/cls-hooked.git#b65ea3b767d5756c71aa8b734c1faac851451dc1"
```

Can anyone tell me how to tell npm / git what protocol to use or do i have to create a ssh key for my ci just for that?

Answer (score 0):

i kind of resolved (i.e. patched) this by explicitly installing the dependency in my package.json so the explicitly installed version was being used by my other dependencies as well. Thus i could define the syntax as follows:
`"cls-hooked": "git+https://git@github.com/alexgarbarev/cls-hooked.git"`

Maybe someone else can use this approach

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I simply ran the `npm i git+https://git@github.com/alexgarbarev/cls-hooked`

Comment: this is what I did, see my answer above. Though this works it brings an unnecessary and undocumented dependency which I would rather avoid

Comment: I came to this page from googling the problem that my package-lock file contains `git+ssh` dependencies. To solve this problem, I simply used my above answer. And then I can simply commit my package-lock to public.